# PHP Files/Directories - .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Alright so this is what the root of my site looks like:

- assets

  - css
  - js
  - img
- .htaccess
- index.php
- page1.php
- page2.php
- page3.php
- style.css

My current .htaccess file works in the sense that it hides .php from the pages which is what i want. So i can access it from http://example.com/page2. But the problem is if i go to http://example.com/page2/ You can see the raw code without any CSS. I want to either redirect users to somewhere else OR have it show it correctly regardless of if there is a "/" or not.

Making it a directory is not an option. It has to be a PHP file in the root.

Current .htaccess file:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
    RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
```

Comment: All of this looks wrong. You're likely curing a symptom and not the case - e.g. relative vs absolute paths.

Comment: Can you post an example of a link to one of your css files?

Comment: Link to CSS file = <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

Comment: The rewrite rule given specifically excludes URLs ending in `/`; does `/page2/` definitely display `page2.php`, or is it some other content? The reason the CSS isn't displaying correctly is that `href="style.css"` means "a file called 'style.css' in the current *URL* directory; to the browser, the directory is `http://example.com/page2/` not `http://example.com/`, as it doesn't know about the rewrite rules. You just need to use a path relative to the domain root instead: `href="/style.css"`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your css links to absolute URLs (the start with a `/`) or add this to the header of your pages:

```
<base href="/">
```